# Is PIC running at 3.3v, 5V logic tolerant?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, digital-logic, logic-level

Can a micro-controller that is capable of running at voltages ranging from 2.3 to 5.5 V, tolerate 5V logic levels while operating at 3.3V?

I need to interface GPS (5V) and raspberry Pi (3.3V) with my microcontroller. Don't have access to logic level shifters.

I am talking about [PIC18F46K22](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41412F.pdf) if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get the voltages for the GPS and the RPi backwards?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry my bad.

Comment: I'm a little confused which device you want to run at 5v, the PIC18F46K22 can operate with a VDD of 5v (page 430 of the datasheet).  It is the PIC18LF46K22 (note the L for low voltage) that is designed for 3.3v systems.

Comment: @tcrosley conceivably, there are other parts running at 3.3v on their board and only the GPS requires 5v.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In section 27.0, "ELECTRICAL CHARACTERISTICS", under "Absolute Maximum Ratings", the third entry states that the voltage on any pin (with a few exceptions) may not be higher than V<sub>DD</sub>+0.3V. This means that the inputs on a 3V3 device are **not** 5V-tolerant. You will *need* to use a level shifter of some sort if you want to connect the GPS to the device.

Comment: Thanks. I should start reading datasheets more thoroughly.

Comment: The inputs of *this* 3V3 volt device are not 5V-tolerant.  There are devices, even in the PIC-line, for which many of the I/O pins are 5V tolerant.

Comment: Sure, but then you have whether or not the 5V GPS is 3V3 tolerant (3V3 CMOS Voh is usually not high enough to reach 5V CMOS Vih).